# Symfony subform attributes not being included in parent

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

So I'm having trouble getting  attributes from subforms.  The scenario is I have made a Work form where the 'employer' is chosen.  If the user is an application admin, they can pick all employers.  If the user is a worker who works with more than one employer, they pick the employer in the form.  Otherwise (if they have a single employer), I want to render a hidden field with the employer set.  Additionally, the Employer subform should handle this by itself.

My strategy was to set some attributes in the employer subform, but when I add these to the workform, they do not come through (specifically, 'value').

Does anyone know how I can propagate these attributes through?

EmployerType (the subform)

```
<?php

namespace Agency\Work\WorkBundle\FormType;

use Agency\Work\WorkBundle\Transformer\EmployerTransformer;
use Agency\Work\WorkBundle\Transformer\SnowflakeTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class EmployerType extends AbstractType
{

    private $options;
    private $usor;
    private $single;
    private $biller;

    // public function __construct($usor) {
    //     $this->usor=$usor;
    public function __construct( array $options=array() ) {
        $this->usor=$options['usor'];
        $this->em=$options['em'];
        $this->single= ( 1 == $this->usor->getEmployer()->count() );
    }

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {

        $builder->create( 'employer'
            , 'entity'
            , array(
                'class'        => 'Agency\Work\WorkBundle\Entity\Employer'
                , 'query_builder' =>
                function ( $repository ) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder( 'b' )
                    ->addOrderBy( 'b.name' );
                    if ( ! $this->usor->isAdmin() ) {
                        $qb->join( 'b.usor', 'u' )->andWhere( "u=$this->usor" );
                    }
                    return $qb;
                }
            )
        )
        ;

        if ($this->single) {
            $builder->setOption('data'
                , $this->single?( $this->usor->getEmployer()->first()->getId() ):''
                );
            $transformer=new EmployerTransformer( $this->em );
            $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
        }

        var_dump($builder->getOptions());
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @param object  $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver ) {
        $resolver->setDefaults( array(
                'class'        => 'Agency\Work\WorkBundle\Entity\Employer'
                , 'label'      => 'Employer'
                , 'label_attr' => array( 'class' => 'txtl' )
            ) );
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return $this->single ? 'hidden' : 'entity';
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @return unknown
     */
    public function getName() {

        return 'employer';
    }

}
```

WorkType (the subform)

```
<?php

namespace Agency\Work\WorkBundle\FormType;

use Agency\Work\WorkBundle\Transformer\EmployerTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class WorkType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
        $securityContext = $options['attr']['securitycontext'];
        if ( isset( $options['attr']['em'] ) ) { $em = $options['attr']['em'];} else {$em=null;}
        $usor    = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        $builder->add(
            $builder->create ( 'employer'
                , new EmployerType( array( 'usor' => $usor, 'em'=>$em ) )
            )
            )
            ;


        $builder
        ->add( 'workDate'
            , null
            , array(
                'label'      => 'End'
                , 'label_attr' => array( 'class' => 'txtl' )
                , 'attr'       => array( 'class' => 'dateEnd' )
            )
        );

    }


    /**
     *
     *
     * @param object  $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver ) {
        $resolver->setDefaults( array(
                'data_class' => 'Agency\Work\WorkBundle\Entity\Consent'
            ) );
    }


    /**
     *
     *
     * @return unknown
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'jobtype';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting code formating, but very difficult to read it. At first glance it seems that the error here

```
'query_builder' =>
                function ( $repository ) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder( 'b' )
                    ->addOrderBy( 'b.name' );
                    if ( ! $this->usor->isAdmin() ) {
                        $qb->join( 'b.usor', 'u' )->andWhere( "u=$this->usor" );
                    }
                    return $qb;
                }
```

You use [closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as a callback function, so need to use `use` keyword to provided context to closure.

```
'query_builder' => function ( $repository ) use ($usor) {
    $qb = $repository
        ->createQueryBuilder( 'b' )
        ->addOrderBy( 'b.name' );
    if ( ! $usor->isAdmin() ) {
        $qb->andWhere('b.usor = :u')->setParameter('u', $usor);
    }
    return $qb;
}
```

Comment: I do agree your style for the closure is better and there was an error there.  However, after fixing as you've recommended the problem remains: the subform's (EmployerType's) attribute does not propagate to the parent form (workType)

Comment: Provide data that you pass to form please. Also that the reason to call `$builder->setOption('data')`?

Comment: set data sets the data.  Anyhows, I've solved this problem with a radically different approach.  I'll accept so noone else spins their wheels here.

Comment: Typically, the data for the form taken from a model or entity. In any case, I am glad that you resolved your problem.